# Finding "the best" individual from the GP

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm

I am referring this algorithm: [A Differential Evolution Algorithm With Dual
Populations for Solving Periodic Railway
Timetable Scheduling Problem](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Yun_Li8/publication/257021757_A_Differential_Evolution_Algorithm_with_Dual_Populations_for_Solving_Periodic_Railway_Timetable_Scheduling_Problem/file/e0b49524b0cc928937.pdf)

And here is the algorithm's part that I am having doubt:

[image]

It is on Page5 in that pdf.

In the first highlight, what does the `as one of the G.p best individuals in GP` ? I didn't got that part. `A` suffix `r1` means, a random row from the `GP` array.

The second thing that I didn't understood was, `A` superfix `g+1` being updated. Or, does it means, just updating the `i`th row of the GP for the next iteration of the while loop?

And the last one is, how we find out the `best` individual!

Comment: You should write a better title, something that refers to the name of the algorithm. Right now, the title and tags are nonsensical and doesn't say anything to anyone about what you're asking for help with.

Comment: Sorry. If you could suggest a title, I would be greatful

Comment: I think it is supposed to mean "G is a number, p is a number, and now consider A_^ to be among the G*p best individuals of the sample". Other than that, no idea. I'm not sure this place is your best bet for a good answer, I'd try CS.

Comment: If it is just a selection of a random A_r1, then the ELSE part is also doing the same! So, there might be some difference in the IF part.

Comment: Maybe it requires that you already have a set of size G*p of individuals you consider the best, then the if case would be "pick one of those" and the else case would be "pick any individual". That's how I would read it on further inspection. Btw, the paper is accessible [here](http://tinyurl.com/p54oc6g) for anyone interested (the tinyurl redirect doesn't work as intended, just delete the "tinyurl" bit at the start of the redirect url).

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere in that paper mentioning that the set is made..! And how would we find out the `best` individual? Do you know how that is being done?

Comment: I have no clue how THE best individual would be chosen, but if you already have a set of the top G*p individuals, you can surely choose one of them at random. I don't know how individuals are ranked, but a cursory reading suggests that there is some efficient method for this in the context of that paper.

Comment: `best` seems to be the row number of the array?